# Request for fb token returns Error 400 in django only in production: "Invalid redirect_uri: The specified URL is not allowed..."

Tags: python, django, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am trying to get long lived an *access token* for fb api in python, django using this tutorial: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/

**This is working locally for me on the development server, but not in production!**

I got a *code* in first step, but have problem with the next step: *Step 6. Exchange the code for an Access Token*

Here is my code to get the access token:

```
    params = {
              'client_id': app_id,
              'client_secret': app_secret,                  
              'code': code,
              'redirect_uri': "http://" + Site.objects.get_current().domain + reverse("login_fb")
    }        
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" + urllib.urlencode(params)  
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers, data=urllib.urlencode(params))        
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

When I call out the request I got an error: *HTTP Error 400: Bad Request*
It was working on the development server. 
When I use `return redirect(url)` instead of `urllib2.urlopen(url)` I am redirected to valid  access token.
Why it doesn't work with *urlopen*?

**UPDATE**
This is response of fb api:

```
Invalid redirect_uri: The specified URL is not allowed by the configuration of the application
```

Comment: I see you are calling urllib2.urlopen(...) with a Request object not a url string

Comment: I was callingwith url string too. It didn't make difference.

Comment: you need to set this url in your application settings on Facebook first.

Comment: Specifically, in basic: "Site URL"

Comment: I set "Site URL" in App settings.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add "localhost" as one your "App Domains" in your Facebook Apps panel

1. https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. "Edit" the app you're trying to debug
3. On the "App Domains" row, enter in `localhost`   (also note the help text for it there which reads:  "Enable auth on domains and subdomain(s)")

Comment: But it was working on localhost. Now I moved it to production server and changed settings to production domain and it doesn't work.

Comment: ahh, I missed that part in your description  (I decided to edit and bold it!)